# typeError: Error #1006: setChildIndex is not a function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Do you know what causes this error?
TypeError: Error #1006: setChildIndex is not a function.
    at Function/()[iVision_Game_fla.MainTimeline::frame83:151]

Here's where I think the error occurs...

```
function dragObject(indx1:int,indx2:int):Function { 
return function(event:MouseEvent){
var item:MovieClip=MovieClip(event.currentTarget); 
item.startDrag(); 
var topPos:uint=this.numChildren-1; 
var itemSound:Sound = new Sound();
itemSound.load(new URLRequest("sounds/"+dirArray[indx1])+indx2+".mp3"));
if(!activeSound)
{
    itemSound.play();
    activeSound=true;
}
this.setChildIndex(item, topPos);
}
```

}

//calling it on another function

```
var functionOnDrag:Function = dragObject(indexc[count-1],index[count2]);
pb[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,functionOnDrag);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think scope is the problem here. If the item's parent isn't changing, you can use item.parent.setChildIndex(item, topPos)

Also, before that, topPos:uint = item.parent.numChildren -1;

Update:

To debug further, put a breakpoint on the line of setChildIndex (151). (adding a breakpoint: click to the left of the line number. it will add a little red circle. When code hits this in debug mode it will stop.)

[image]
Then go to Debug -> Debug Movie -> Debug

When it stops, open the Debug Panels: Window->Debug Panels->Variables, Window->Debug Panels->Callstack

In the variable panel, you should see all the current variables in the scope. What you are looking for is an issue with the object that setChildIndex is being called on. In this case, the parent of item. You can drill down to see what that is. It should be a DisplayObjectContainer (MovieClip, Sprite, etc...). Item came from event, so i would check event.currentTarget as well. You are basically trying to confirm that at that breakpoint, item exists, it has a parent, and it's parent is a DisplayObjectController. If one of these isn't true, you can track backwards from here why this isn't the case.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, but I dont really understand cause I'm new to as3...I've tried your suggestion but when I clicked that item it disappears

Comment: it's functioning but I'm worried what will be the effect of it on my application

Comment: it's the same as the what we've started

Comment: yes the error occurs on this line "this.setChildIndex(item,topPos)"

Comment: it shows this "TypeError: Error #1006: setChildIndex is not a function. at Function/<anonymous>()[iVision_Game_fla.MainTimeline::frame83:151]"

Comment: Updated the post and deleted my comments to tidy this space up. I may be missing something, but i would think that would work. I added how I would debug this further. If you still have no luck after trying, i'd be happy to dig through source code if you feel like uploading it somewhere.

Comment: thanks that solved my problem...I just replaced "this.numChildren-1" to "item.parent.numChildren-1" **and** "this.setChildIndex(item,topPos)" to "item.parent.setChildIndex(item,topPos) what I did before was changing either of the two but not both...

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Error #1006: setChildIndex is not a function

You have created anonymous function, if you want capture `this`, you could do such construction:

```
var selfRef:MyClass = this;
```

Now your handler for the MouseEvent will look:

```
function dragObject(indx1:int, indx2:int):Function {
    return function (event:MouseEvent) {
        //Your code
        selfRef.setChildIndex(item, topPos);
    }
}
```